# Why does this invoke?

Tags: javascript, jquery, setinterval

Just curious why setInterval invokes via a variable assignment?
I figure setInterval has special scope or something of the like?

```js
    mobileBlink();

    function mobileBlink(){

        var blinker = function(){
            jQuery('.navbar-toggle').fadeTo(1500, 0.4).fadeTo(1400, 1.0);
        }

        //Why does this invoke?
        var triggerA = setInterval(blinker, 2000);


        //Why does this not invoke?
        var alerta = function(){
          alert('huh');
        };

        jQuery('.navbar-toggle').click(function(){
          clearInterval(triggerA);
        });

      }
```

Any info would be great.

Comment: Are you asking about the use of `blinker` or the use of `triggerA = setInterval()`?

Comment: It's not really clear what you are asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first case you're invoking the function -indicated by the parenthesis with parameters, i.e. `(blinker, 2000)` - and you're assigning the **result** of this invocation (whatever the function returns) to the variable.

In the second case, there are no parenthesis after the function, so it's not invoked. You're just assigning **the function itself** to a variable.

If you add parenthesis to your 2nd case, it will invoke and you will see the alert, e.g.:
`var alerta = function(){alert('huh');}();` - notice the `()` at the end.

By the way, don't be confused by the parenthesis in the function definition, i.e. the parenthesis at the end of `function()`. These just indicate that you're about to define a function with no parameters, it's not an actual invocation. It's parenthesis **after** the function that count. E.g you can do:
`alert(function(foo){return foo * 3;}(100));` and it will alert "300". The first parenthesis, `(foo)`, indicate that the function takes 1 parameter called `foo`. The 2nd parenthesis `(100)`, after the function, actually invoke the function with a parameter (100 in this case).

Comment: Gotcha,

So we can assign a function to a variable and as long as it is invoked it will act as per usual...meaning:

var triggerA = setInterval(blinker, 2000);

is the same as 

setInterval(blinker, 2000);

Except the former adds the result to the variable.

Sound ok?

Comment: @bubbaShrimp: Well, you don't really assign the function to a variable, you assign the *return value* of the function (in this case). Some functions return values. You have to assign those values to something in order to do something with the values.

Comment: Coolio. Thanks to you both.

Answer (score 0):

It gives a handle that can later be used to clear the timer.

```
clearInterval(triggerA);
```

Answer (score 0):

The following line:

```
var triggerA = setInterval(blinker, 2000);
```

Doesn't actually invoke any functions except `setInterval`.

That function accepts two arguments: one function, and one number representing the millisecond length of the interval offsets between invocations of the first argument.

`setInterval`, the function, will handle the invocation of the passed in function by calling it with something like `arg1()`. Note the parentheses.

As for your second question, the function isn't getting invoked because all you're doing is defining the variable `alerta` as a reference to the anonymous function written. To invoke the function, there needs to be an explicit call (there are lots of ways to invoke a function).

The difference is that one is an explicit invocation of a function (in this case, directly calling the function by its name), and the other is a function definition, but you're simply setting that variable as a reference to the function.

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
var triggerA = setInterval(blinker, 2000);
```

is actually invoking(calling) the function `setInterval`. And, as previously mentioned, setInterval does return a value.

Here, you are creating the function:

```
var alerta = function(){
    alert('huh');
};
```

`function` is a keyword in Javascript that tells it you are defining a function, not calling it.

`setInterval` is the name of a function, so it assumes you are calling that function since you have parens`()` after it.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

setInterval is a function like any other. `triggerA` is the value returned by that function.

In contrast, `alerta` references the function itself, not the value it returns, because you haven't asked it to execute yet. You've just defined it.